# How do I add text to a multi-paged Tiff in Java and maintain image scale?

Tags: java, text, addition, tiff

Trying to add a text to a multi-paged (multiple image) tiff file.

to make the process the text is added correctly, but the image created is not equal to the original zoom (scale) of content changes. I do not know how to make it equal to the original image.

This is the code I use:

```
File file = new File("AA005E57.tif");                           
SeekableStream seekableStream = new FileSeekableStream(file);          
BufferedImage bsrc = ImageIO.read(file);          

ImageDecoder decoder = ImageCodec.createImageDecoder("tiff", seekableStream, null);
int numPages = decoder.getNumPages();
BufferedImage image[]= new BufferedImage[numPages];        
for(int i=0;i<decoder.getNumPages();i++){
    PlanarImage op1 =    new NullOpImage(decoder.decodeAsRenderedImage(i), null, null, OpImage.OP_IO_BOUND);

    BufferedImage pg1 = convertRenderedImage(op1);// (new BufferedImage(op1.getWidth(), op1.getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY));
    image[i] = pg1;
    Graphics2D g2 = image[i].createGraphics();
    float pageWidthInch = image[i].getWidth() * 72 / 200;
    float pageHeightInch = image[i].getHeight() * 72 / 100;
    g2.scale(pageWidthInch, pageHeightInch);
    if (i == 0 ){
        Font font = new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 12);
        g2.setColor(Color.black);
        g2.setFont(font);
        g2.drawString("RADICADO 1234567890214365-D", 25,pg1.getHeight()-25);
    }

    g2.drawImage(image[i], (image[i].getWidth()),image[i].getHeight() ,null);

    g2.dispose();
}
save(image,"C:/Prueb-18.tif");
```

Code for `convertRenderedImage`:

```
if (img instanceof BufferedImage) {
    return (BufferedImage)img;  
}   

ColorModel cm = img.getColorModel();

float pageWidthInch = img.getWidth() * 72 / 200;
float pageHeightInch = img.getHeight() * 72 / 100;

WritableRaster raster = cm.createCompatibleWritableRaster( (int)pageWidthInch,(int)pageHeightInch);
boolean isAlphaPremultiplied = cm.isAlphaPremultiplied();
Hashtable properties = new Hashtable();
String[] keys = img.getPropertyNames();
if (keys!=null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        properties.put(keys[i], img.getProperty(keys[i]));

    }
}
BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(cm, raster, false, properties);
img.copyData(raster);

return result;
```

Code for Save method:

```
Iterator writers = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("TIFF");

if (writers == null || !writers.hasNext()) {
    throw new RuntimeException("No writers are available.");
}

FileImageOutputStream fios = new FileImageOutputStream(new File(tif));

ImageWriter writer = (ImageWriter) writers.next();
writer.setOutput(fios);
writer.prepareWriteSequence(null);
ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();  
param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);  
param.setCompressionType("CCITT T.4");
for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    ImageTypeSpecifier imageType = ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromRenderedImage(b[i]);            
    IIOMetadata imageMetadata = writer.getDefaultImageMetadata(imageType, param);
    imageMetadata = createImageMetadata(imageMetadata);
    writer.writeToSequence(new IIOImage(b[i], null, imageMetadata),param);      
}

writer.endWriteSequence();
writer.dispose();
writer = null;
fios.close();

}
```

Code for createImageMetadata:

```
char[] COMPRESSION = new char[] { (char) BaselineTIFFTagSet.COMPRESSION_CCITT_T_4 };
char[] INCH_RESOLUTION_UNIT = new char[] { 2 };
char[] BITS_PER_SAMPLE = new char[] { 1 };
long[][] X_DPI_RESOLUTION = new long[][] { { 200, 1 } };
long[][] Y_DPI_RESOLUTION = new long[][] { { 200, 1 } };

TIFFDirectory ifd = TIFFDirectory.createFromMetadata(imageMetadata);

BaselineTIFFTagSet base = BaselineTIFFTagSet.getInstance();

TIFFTag tagResUnit = base.getTag(BaselineTIFFTagSet.TAG_RESOLUTION_UNIT);
TIFFTag tagXRes = base.getTag(BaselineTIFFTagSet.TAG_X_RESOLUTION);
TIFFTag tagYRes = base.getTag(BaselineTIFFTagSet.TAG_Y_RESOLUTION);

TIFFTag tagBitSample = base.getTag(BaselineTIFFTagSet.TAG_BITS_PER_SAMPLE);

TIFFTag tagRowStrips = base.getTag(BaselineTIFFTagSet.TAG_ROWS_PER_STRIP);

TIFFTag tagCompression = base.getTag(BaselineTIFFTagSet.TAG_COMPRESSION);

TIFFField fieldResUnit = new TIFFField(tagResUnit, TIFFTag.TIFF_SHORT, 1, INCH_RESOLUTION_UNIT);
TIFFField fieldXRes = new TIFFField(tagXRes, TIFFTag.TIFF_RATIONAL, 1, X_DPI_RESOLUTION);
TIFFField fieldYRes = new TIFFField(tagYRes, TIFFTag.TIFF_RATIONAL, 1, Y_DPI_RESOLUTION);
TIFFField fieldBitSample = new TIFFField(tagBitSample, TIFFTag.TIFF_SHORT, 1, BITS_PER_SAMPLE);
TIFFField fieldCompression = new TIFFField(tagCompression, TIFFTag.TIFF_SHORT, 1, COMPRESSION);

ifd.addTIFFField(fieldResUnit);
ifd.addTIFFField(fieldXRes);
ifd.addTIFFField(fieldYRes);
ifd.addTIFFField(fieldBitSample);
ifd.addTIFFField(fieldCompression);
return ifd.getAsMetadata();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code is inconsistent:

```
float pageWidthInch = image[i].getWidth() * 72 / 200;
float pageHeightInch = image[i].getHeight() * 72 / 100;
```

Is your source DPI 200x100?  Be consistent on input; choose 100 or 200.  This might be the source of your problem, especially since you save both as 200 for output.  Both should likely be the same value, unless your source uses a different DPI for height and width.

Note that this code appears **twice** in your submitted code above.

If you need to, use [AsTiffTagViewer](http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/astifftagviewer.html) (free application I have found invaluable for examining TIFF files) on your source image to confirm the appropriate values of each page.

---

Alternately after further review, you do this:

```
g2.scale(pageWidthInch, pageHeightInch);
```

Have you considered leaving out this call to `g2.scale()`?

Comment: Hello, DPI code and remove it and continue the same, the generated image is not equal to the original image. Follow distorted. Review what to AsTiffTagViewer.
If you happen to have any other way to add text to a shape preserving orginal tif, I would greatly appreciate it.

thanks

Comment: Open your source image using AsTiffTagViewer.  Click "Copy Tags as Text" for each page.  Edit your original post to include the information.  Open your generated image using AsTiffTagViewer.  Click "Copy Tags as Text" for each first page.  Edit your original post to include the information.

Comment: This will also help us confirm what the scale of your original TIFF was; sometimes it is Centimeters.  Also note that I added a suggestion to remove your call to g2.scale() in the answer above.  Please investigate.

Comment: Are you going to update the post with your data from the Tiff Tag Viewer?